# I want to merge two query to have one result

Tags: mysql, sql, join

This is my first Query that it give me sum of actual and estimated expenses related to salaries

```
SELECT
  d.y_                                   AS `salaries`
 , IFNULL(SUM(d.actual),0)               AS `Estimated`
 , IFNULL(SUM(d.estimated),0)            AS `Actual`
FROM (
SELECT estimated_type                       AS`y_`
    ,null                                       AS `Estimated`
    , sum(estimated_amount)                     AS `Actual`
FROM bacci.estimated_expenses_table it
WHERE it.estimated_year = '2017'
    AND it.estimated_type = 'management'
GROUP
    BY YEAR(it.estimated_year)
         union all
SELECT Type_expenses_table                      AS`y_`
    ,SUM(it.Amount_expenses_table)              AS `Estimated`
    , null                                      AS `Actual`
FROM bacci.expenses_table it
WHERE it.Date_expenses_table >= '2017-01-01'
        AND it.Date_expenses_table  < '2017-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
        AND it.Type_expenses_table = 'management'
GROUP
     BY YEAR(it.Date_expenses_table)
         union all
SELECT estimated_type                           AS`y_`
    ,null                                       AS `Estimated`
    , sum(estimated_amount)                     AS `Actual`
FROM bacci.estimated_expenses_table it
WHERE it.estimated_year = '2017'
    AND it.estimated_type = 'staff salaries'
GROUP
     BY YEAR(it.estimated_year)
         union all
SELECT Type_expenses_table                      AS`y_`
    ,SUM(it.Amount_expenses_table)              AS `Estimated`
    , null                                      AS `Actual`
FROM bacci.expenses_table it
WHERE it.Date_expenses_table >= '2017-01-01'
        AND it.Date_expenses_table  < '2017-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
        AND it.Type_expenses_table = 'staff salaries'
GROUP
     BY YEAR(it.Date_expenses_table)
) d
 GROUP
 BY d.y_

ORDER
 BY d.y_;
```

The result:

[image]

My second Query that it give me sum of actual and estimated expenses related to equipments

```
SELECT
  d.y_                                   AS `Equipments`
 , IFNULL(SUM(d.actual),0)               AS `Estimated`
 , IFNULL(SUM(d.estimated),0)            AS `Actual`
FROM (
    select estimated_type                       AS`y_`
    ,null                                       AS `Estimated`
    , sum(estimated_amount)                     AS `Actual`
FROM bacci.estimated_expenses_table it
WHERE it.estimated_year = '2017'
    and it.estimated_type = 'vehicle rent'
GROUP
     BY YEAR(it.estimated_year)
         union all
SELECT Type_expenses_table                      AS`y_`
    ,SUM(it.Amount_expenses_table)              AS `Estimated`
    , null                                      AS `Actual`
FROM bacci.expenses_table it
WHERE it.Date_expenses_table >= '2017-01-01'
        AND it.Date_expenses_table  < '2017-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
        and it.Type_expenses_table = 'vehicle rent'
GROUP
     BY YEAR(it.Date_expenses_table)
         union all
SELECT estimated_type                         AS`y_`
    ,null                                     AS `Estimated`
    , sum(estimated_amount)                   AS `Actual`
FROM bacci.estimated_expenses_table it
WHERE it.estimated_year = '2017'
    and it.estimated_type = 'vehicle fuel'
GROUP
     BY YEAR(it.estimated_year)     
         union all
SELECT Type_expenses_table                      AS`y_`
    ,SUM(it.Amount_expenses_table)              AS `Estimated`
    , null                                      AS `Actual`
FROM bacci.expenses_table it
WHERE it.Date_expenses_table >= '2017-01-01'
        AND it.Date_expenses_table  < '2017-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
        and it.Type_expenses_table = 'vehicle fuel'
GROUP
     BY YEAR(it.Date_expenses_table)
                  union all
SELECT estimated_type                         AS`y_`
    ,null                                     AS `Estimated`
    , sum(estimated_amount)                   AS `Actual`
FROM bacci.estimated_expenses_table it
WHERE it.estimated_year = '2017'
    and it.estimated_type = 'generator fuel'
GROUP
     BY YEAR(it.estimated_year) 
         union all
SELECT Type_expenses_table                      AS`y_`
    ,SUM(it.Amount_expenses_table)              AS `Estimated`
    , null                                      AS `Actual`
FROM bacci.expenses_table it
WHERE it.Date_expenses_table >= '2017-01-01'
        AND it.Date_expenses_table  < '2017-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
        and it.Type_expenses_table = 'generator fuel'
GROUP
     BY YEAR(it.Date_expenses_table)
) d
  GROUP
  BY d.y_

ORDER
  BY d.y_;
```

The result:

[image]

I want to have Salaries under it management and staff salaries
than Equipments under it Vehicle Rent, Vehicle fuel and Generator Fuel etcetera

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use UNION to merge those queries:

```
SELECT [First query]
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Equipments', 'Estimated', 'Actual'
UNION ALL
SELECT [Second query]
```

Please note that the Select after the first UNION ALL simply selects the headlines for your second query. You also could use UNION (w/o ALL), because it does not look like you're having duplicates.

Comment: i want to have Equipments, Estimated, Actual. if i do this it give me Equipments, 0, 0

Comment: I did this select(select ....) union all SELECT 'Equipments', 'Estimated', 'Actual' union all select (select...) when I execute the query it throw this Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Try it with writing `SELECT ...` instead of `SELECT(SELECT ...)`, but remove the `ORDER BY` clauses from the first `SELECT` and change the one of the second `SELECT` to `ORDER BY (1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have duplicate registries and dont want to see them, u can use UNION ALL. if u dont mind duplicate registries u can use UNION.
here is and example

`SELECT [query_1]
UNION ALL
SELECT [query_2]
UNION ALL
SELECT [query_3]`

Comment: it give this Error Code: 1221. Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Comment: You need to order after the last union. Simply remove the ORDER BY clauses from your queries and add "ORDER BY (1)" after your last SELECT-statement